# What does the joke "leave you Clampetts alone to your banjo lesson", from 3rd Rock From the Sun mean?

Tags: reference, 3rd-rock-from-the-sun

In Season 1, episode 4, Sally talks to Dick and she and Dr. Albright say the following;

> **Sally:** Well, why didn't you say so? I mean, if sex is so important, you and I can do it right here on the desk, get it out of the way.
>
> **Albright:** Okay... I'll leave you Clampetts alone to your banjo lesson.

What does "leave you Clampetts alone to your banjo lesson" mean?

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Sorry for the rollback, but I think the TV ID tag was added by accident (though I could be wrong).

Comment: @No worries. The current tagging (and title) is indeed better.

Answer (score 19):

She's referencing the protagonists of [*The Beverly Hillbillies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beverly_Hillbillies).

> The Beverly Hillbillies is an American sitcom originally broadcast on CBS for nine seasons, from September 26, 1962, to March 23, 1971. The show had an ensemble cast which features Buddy Ebsen, Irene Ryan, Donna Douglas, and Max Baer Jr. as **a poor backwoods family [The Clampetts] who move to Beverly Hills, California, after striking oil on their land.**

She's basically using this reference to call their practices primitive. US 'hillbilly' stereotypes include *banjo playing, inbreeding* and crass, uncultured traditions and behavior (although these stereotypes are mostly broad and insulting). Dr. Albright is saying it in reference to Sally's casual suggestion of having sex with her brother Dick on his desk. Of course, they aren't really related, but Dr. Albright doesn't know this yet at this point in the series.

The Solomons, like the Clampetts, are plucked from their home and placed in an environment they're aliens to (only this time *literally*) and a lot of the humor is similarly derived from their own peculiar ways and their naive interpretations of local customs.

Comment: I think the focus in your answer should be pertaining to the inbreeding nature of stereotypical hillbillies. She's referring to a brother and sister having sex as hillbillies.. the insinuation is obvious.

Comment: @GrayRoberts Well, I did mention it. I tried to be succint. ;) I'll elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, I did see the inbreeding comment, but I thought the focus was certainly in reference to their being siblings, rather than a reference to The Beverley Hillbillies.

Will upvote you 'cause it's a good answer however.

Comment: Slight edit, Dick and Sally aren't really related.

Comment: Slight niggle: "alien" means, _literally_, foreign, so the Clampetts are as literally alien to their new environment as the _space_ aliens are to earth.

Comment: @Williham language has evolved and made that definition of alien obsolete/obscure in typical conversation though.

Comment: @cde I mean, I _see_ what you mean, but a) Unless you think extraterrestrial invaders are arriving from Mexico, that doesn't really hold up, and b) You were the one to say _literally_. "Alien" is still very much used to mean "foreign", rather than "from space".

Comment: @WillihamTotland I wrote that, actually. ;) And though the Clampetts' home state is a bit of a mystery (they're presumably from the Ozarks), they're still Americans. I wouldn't term them 'aliens' just because they moved from there to California.

Comment: @Walt A) my bad. and B) they are still foreign (i.e. alien) to their environment